# Find string inside files and replace with a new string

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I need to find all files containing certain text inside my project directory. 
This includes sub-directories.

I've managed to find all the files:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -H 'Rename' {} \;
```

[image]

Now I need to replace the keyword "Rename" with "XYZ" leaving the rest of text in each file intact.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`sed` instead of `grep`.

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/Rename/XYZ/g' {} \;
```

`grep` already scans all the lines of every file, so you aren't losing anything. This just makes the change when it finds it, instead of printing out the line.